# iOS Inter App communication using URL Schemes

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have 2 iPhone apps installed in the same device, app A and app B. app A doesn't have any remote server connectivity. app A has to invoke app B for the remote server communication. app B will make the server call & will return the response to app A. I want to use 'Apple URL Schemes' for this Inter App communication. The issue is that when app A invoke app B, app A will go to background and app B will come foreground. But I want this communication to happen without user notice. Always app A should be in the foreground for the user.

So the solution can be like this. app A invokes app b for the server call. app A will enter background mode and app B will come foreground. The method in the app A will detect the background mode & will bring it back to foreground. Similarly, method in app B will detect the foreground mode & will bring it back to background in some fraction of seconds. So the user will see only some flashing of screens when the apps switch.  app B will execute the task in background & will return the result to app A.

I want to know whether this can be handled in iOS? Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: what happens if the user uninstall one of your apps? i can't image why u want two apps... avoiding updating `app A`? maybe we can solve the root problem, if you clearify your idea.

Comment: @donmarkusi This is the requirement from the client. There might be multiple apps in the device from the same vendor. But only one app will be having access to remote server. Other apps in the device need to communicate with this app for remote server connectivity.

Comment: @SinuVarghese I am also trying to achieve the same process. Where you able to complete this requirement? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try something like that. I'm theorizing here, not sure if step #5-6 will actually work, but I think it worth trying

- App A calls app B via URL scheme: `openUrl: @"appB://startsomething"`
- App B become active and user will see that switch
- App B starts network communication and immediately sends control back to the app A: `openUrl: @"appA://resume`
- App A become active and user will see that switch again (so essentially app A will flick to app B and back
- App B meanwhile is processing network request and when it completes it sends information to the App A using openUrl again: `openUrl: @"appA://data=GOT_DATA"`
- App A is already active but it should receive this call and parse the data out

Comment: Is there any limitation in size to send data via inter app communication?

Comment: Is it possible to make App B without any UI, so that the user will always see App A?

Comment: No. You can not have an app w/o UI

Comment: @sha When App A becomes active again, does it change the previous state of the app?

Comment: @dariru it depends how you will implement the handler of opening with URL in appA. You can do whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

it can be handled PARTLY.

a can use b for the server call

but b has to stay in foreground to invoke the url back to a

Comment: when app A enters background, automatically it has to bounce back to foreground mode. Is it can be done in some fraction of second so that the user can't see app B running ?

Comment: yes, it will not happen automatically. I want to programmatically handle it. Why can't b invoke a when it is in background.

Comment: Because being in the background means that it can't do certain things.

Comment: Is there any other inter app communication solution available in iOS for this scenario?

Comment: nothing without user interaction / at least not public ;) privately there IS of course XPC but for us ..no

Answer (score 0):

If one fix the scope in the question (like URL Scheme), you are limited by the scope.  But if one free oneself, one may ask or keep on asking such as - is the App extension later help this question.